# How to get first Cell of CollectionView?

Tags: swift, collectionview

I want to change first cell's background color when Vc get notification. And I use the code like blow to achieve this, but it always get nil:

```
 @objc func getNotification() {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? TestCell {
            cell.changeBackgroundColor()
        }
 }
```

and if I print visibelCells I got 6 different cell object!(It only show three on screen, and models.count also is 3), here is my log print visibleCells.

```
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbb6a5560; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (58969.7 18.4; 353.7 115.2); transform = [0.90000000000000002, 0, 0, 0.90000000000000002, 0, 0]; alpha = 0.6; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000ccd9a0>>
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbb74c2b0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (58950 0; 393 128); layer = <CALayer: 0x600000cd8a20>>
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbe06c560; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (58989.3 24.8; 314.4 102.4); transform = [0.80000000000000004, 0, 0, 0.80000000000000004, 0, 0]; alpha = 0.2; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000cdd3e0>>
>>> -----------------------
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbb6a5560; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (58969.7 18.4; 353.7 115.2); transform = [0.90000000000000002, 0, 0, 0.90000000000000002, 0, 0]; alpha = 0.6; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000ccd9a0>>
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbb74c2b0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (58950 0; 393 128); layer = <CALayer: 0x600000cd8a20>>
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbe06c560; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (58989.3 24.8; 314.4 102.4); transform = [0.80000000000000004, 0, 0, 0.80000000000000004, 0, 0]; alpha = 0.2; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000cdd3e0>>
>>> -----------------------
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbb6a5560; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (59343 0; 393 128); layer = <CALayer: 0x600000ccd9a0>>
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbb663b90; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (59382.3 24.8; 314.4 102.4); transform = [0.80000000000000004, 0, 0, 0.80000000000000004, 0, 0]; alpha = 0.2; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000cd6d40>>
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbe06c560; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (59362.7 18.4; 353.7 115.2); transform = [0.90000000000000002, 0, 0, 0.90000000000000002, 0, 0]; alpha = 0.6; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000cdd3e0>>
>>> -----------------------
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbb74c2b0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (59775.3 24.8; 314.4 102.4); transform = [0.80000000000000004, 0, 0, 0.80000000000000004, 0, 0]; alpha = 0.2; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000cd8a20>>
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbb663b90; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (59755.7 18.4; 353.7 115.2); transform = [0.90000000000000002, 0, 0, 0.90000000000000002, 0, 0]; alpha = 0.6; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000cd6d40>>
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbe06c560; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (59736 0; 393 128); layer = <CALayer: 0x600000cdd3e0>>
>>> -----------------------
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbb55f6f0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (58969.7 18.4; 353.7 115.2); transform = [0.90000000000000002, 0, 0, 0.90000000000000002, 0, 0]; alpha = 0.6; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000cc84c0>>
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbb55a1e0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (58950 0; 393 128); layer = <CALayer: 0x600000d68000>>
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbe06c560; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (58989.3 24.8; 314.4 102.4); transform = [0.80000000000000004, 0, 0, 0.80000000000000004, 0, 0]; alpha = 0.2; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000cdd3e0>>
>>> -----------------------
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbb55f6f0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (59343 0; 393 128); layer = <CALayer: 0x600000cc84c0>>
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbb6a5560; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (59382.3 24.8; 314.4 102.4); transform = [0.80000000000000004, 0, 0, 0.80000000000000004, 0, 0]; alpha = 0.2; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000ccd9a0>>
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbe06c560; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (59362.7 18.4; 353.7 115.2); transform = [0.90000000000000002, 0, 0, 0.90000000000000002, 0, 0]; alpha = 0.6; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000cdd3e0>>
>>> -----------------------
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbb55a1e0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (59775.3 24.8; 314.4 102.4); transform = [0.80000000000000004, 0, 0, 0.80000000000000004, 0, 0]; alpha = 0.2; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000d68000>>
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbb6a5560; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (59755.7 18.4; 353.7 115.2); transform = [0.90000000000000002, 0, 0, 0.90000000000000002, 0, 0]; alpha = 0.6; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000ccd9a0>>
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbe06c560; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (59736 0; 393 128); layer = <CALayer: 0x600000cdd3e0>>
>>> -----------------------
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbb663b90; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (58969.7 18.4; 353.7 115.2); transform = [0.90000000000000002, 0, 0, 0.90000000000000002, 0, 0]; alpha = 0.6; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000cd6d40>>
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbb74c2b0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (58950 0; 393 128); layer = <CALayer: 0x600000cd8a20>>
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbe06c560; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (58989.3 24.8; 314.4 102.4); transform = [0.80000000000000004, 0, 0, 0.80000000000000004, 0, 0]; alpha = 0.2; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000cdd3e0>>
>>> -----------------------
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbb663b90; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (59343 0; 393 128); layer = <CALayer: 0x600000cd6d40>>
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbb55f6f0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (59382.3 24.8; 314.4 102.4); transform = [0.80000000000000004, 0, 0, 0.80000000000000004, 0, 0]; alpha = 0.2; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000cc84c0>>
>>> visibleCells:  <TestCell: 0x7fccbe06c560; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (59362.7 18.4; 353.7 115.2); transform = [0.90000000000000002, 0, 0, 0.90000000000000002, 0, 0]; alpha = 0.6; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000cdd3e0>>
>>> -----------------------
```

Comment: Code looks good to me... what happens when you do "as! TestCell"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is wrong. Don't try to find a cell on screen and change the way it looks.

Update your collection view's model data when you get your notification, and then tell the collection view to reload the affected cell(s).

Comment: thx, right, always remember to update data, not deal cell directly.